# Can I view a list of my "great comments", perhaps in my profile?

Tags: discussion, comments, profile-page

I'm a little surprised no one asked this yet, but why isn't it possible to show your comments in descending order of "great comment" votes it has received? You can do this with upvotes on questions and answers, and since I think comments are the third major activity on SO, I'd like to view them. Even if you couldn't order them, it should at least show the number of votes on the activity#comments page of your profile...

Comment: Because no one cares about comments.

Comment: @TheEstablishment Oops. What if I do? :)

Comment: Then you're in the minority.

Comment: `I think comments are the third major activity on SO` Argh... (how's that for a "major" activity ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) queries that you might find interesting:

- [Top 100 most upvoted comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67902/top-100-most-upvoted-comments),
- [My Most Popular Comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66765/my-most-popular-comments)

Going through the first query, you'll soon understand why [no one really cares about comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130906/show-great-comment-votes-in-list/130908#comment360238_130906), they are pure noise. And let's not forget that comments are ephemeral... I know of at least one moderator who absolutely hates them and misses no opportunity to delete them.

---

Here's my most popular comments:

```
Votes  Site         Comment

31     ProgSE       `Am I a tad too OCD?` Yes. But so am I, so +1 for asking this...
15     ProgSE Meta  Flogging a dead horse is fine. Disguising it as a farewell post is tactless, at best.   
41     SO           6. Fight depression  
18     MSO          Wonder what's the current price for ♦ accounts...
```

There's nothing wrong with these comments, but none of them is particularly useful and I have no idea why people up voted them. No real value in having them displayed prominently on my profile(s), the SEDE queries are good enough if the only thing you are looking for is to satisfy your curiosity.

Comment: I think I'm mistaken about what my userID is... If I run the query with `162704` which I thought would be yours, it returns nothing..

Comment: @Mario the ID is per site. That query is for Stack Overflow so for that site "Yahoo" ID is actually 99456.

Comment: @Mario You can find the user ID by visiting the [site profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1313143/mario-de-schaepmeester), it's the number on the url. For Stack Overflow yours is 1313143 and mine 99456, and for Meta it's 183189 (you) and 162704 (me).

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast Okay, then i was right about it. How come the query doesn't return any results? I just enter the number, nothing more than that, in the input field.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester Hm? Are you sure you are using SEDE for the correct site? Perhaps you are using my MSO user ID on SO data or vice versa?

Comment: Yes I've checked. I'm not logged in though, does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester Oops! You are very new ;) SEDE's data are updated monthly (roughly) and the last update was on March 14 (check the [SEDE frontpage](http://data.stackexchange.com/)), so you get no results because according to SEDE you don't exist (yet). We don't know when the next update will be, it's already late.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester That is a mystery to me... It could be that you'll need to log in, but honestly I don't know. If it's not that, try asking around on the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), there are people there that are far more experienced with SEDE than I am.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast Never mind, my first attempt with your ID was indeed with your MSO ID instead of your normal SO one :) my fault.

Comment: +1 @Yannis Rizos nice thanks i didnt know about data explorer ! but why is my id not found ! **UPDATE :** oops i think i found it

Comment: @cptloop has a humble reputation of 485, but the **SECOND** greatest comment with 1083 upvotes!! https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/30146633