# How to know which comments got great comments and the number of them too?

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I view a list of my “great comments”, perhaps in my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130906/can-i-view-a-list-of-my-great-comments-perhaps-in-my-profile)

Is there any way I can know the number of great comments that I've got, for my comments posted?
We usually post a lot of comments in SO and other sites. How can we know which comments among these got great comments(+1), and how much rating it got?

Comment: Even if my comment has received +1, how can I track those comments and see the number of great comments?

Comment: @TheEstablishment If I fail to remember dupes I've answered, I'm getting old... <sigh>

Comment: @Yannis I cheated by changing the title a little bit :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ["My most upvoted comments" query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70480/my-most-upvoted-comments) on Stack Exchange Data Explorer is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: But I want the list of all comments(my comments), which received (+1) or more. Can be even +1 too and not necessarily highest.

Comment: @Ajj And that's what the query does more or less. If it doesn't do _exactly_ what you want, you can always try writing your own query, that's what the Data Explorer is there for.

Comment: post link and comment link is coming up as null. You have got me half of my answer ..

Comment: @Ajj Make sure you're using your own user id (`818557`) and lower the `CutoffScore`, your most upvoted comment is at +3, the query won't return anything if the `CutoffScore` is larger than 2.

Comment: I had given my id and cutoff as 1

Comment: Selecting Score,PostId, Id did it. thanks !!!